# E: Unable to locate package php-gettext

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, php-gettext

running OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on Digital Ocean Droplet
mysql: 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
php: 8.1.5

I followed this tutorial on **installing phpmyadmin**: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04
and when I try to access phpmyadmin, I get a blank page. I've google it, and seems like I'm **missing an extension called: php-gettext**.
When I try to install it, I get "Unable to locate package". (PS: I've apt-get update before running)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gettext
```

instead of:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working.. getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install php-php-gettext`

Comment: I have tried this but not working.. getting same error